# glm: cannot use toMat4 from quaternion.hpp

Tags: c++, glm-math

I get an error when I try to use glm. Some functions of glm work. However I cannot use all overloads and quaternion related thing.

```
    1>src\foo.cpp(369): error C2039: 'toMat4': is not a member of 'glm'
    1>          d:\..\glm\glm\gtc\type_ptr.inl(35): note: see declaration of 'glm'
    1>src\foo.cpp(369): error C3861: 'toMat4': identifier not found
```

with this:

```
    #include <glm/glm.hpp> //vec3, vec4, ivec4, mat4
    #include <glm/common.hpp> //vec3, vec4, ivec4, mat4
    #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
    #include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
    #include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>

    glm::mat4 t1 = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(), -piv);
    glm::mat4 rot = glm::toMat4(trafo.orientation);
    glm::mat4 t2 = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(), piv);
```

Comment: Are you using the lastest glm version ? Which Compiler do you use ?
And with including <glm/glm.hpp> you dont have to include anything else.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation it is listed in the glm::gtx namespace. Have a look here:

https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.0/api/a00184.html

But you can also use:

```
detail::tmat4x4<T> glm::gtc::quaternion::mat4_cast  (   detail::tquat< T > const &      x   )
```

Which you have included. Look here:

https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.0/api/a00135.html#ae2d14d52f9fef3da00cf867f9e2e3dfa

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem including this:

```
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
```